# PHP HTML image output

Tags: php, html, gd, image

In the [`PHP manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) for [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) I saw the following script for outputting an image.

```
<?php

$imgfile = "test.gif";

$handle = fopen($filename, "r");

$imgbinary = fread(fopen($imgfile, "r"), filesize($imgfile));

echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary) . '" />';

?>
```

But *how* can you output an image dynamically created with [`GD`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)?

I've tried this:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 200, 0xFF0000);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 200, 0, 400, 200, 0x0000FF);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 200, 200, 400, 0xFFFF00);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 200, 200, 400, 400, 0x00FF00);

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(imagepng($im)).'" />';
```

Why doesn't that work?

It seems to work in **IE** but not **Firefox**.  How can I make it **cross-browser?**

Comment: No, firefox.  Hmm, it works in IE...

Comment: Do you have a real need to use data: URIs? Because if you don't, it's better not to use them. They have an awful lot of downsides. IE < 8 doesn't support them at all, for example.

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors/3386050#3386050

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, sorry, I was thinking too fast :)

`imagepng()` will output raw data stream *directly* to the browser, so you must use `ob_start()` and other output buffering handles to obtain it.

Here you are:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($yourGdImageHandle);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

That is - you need to use `$output` variable for you `base64_encode()` function.

Comment: @Mark no, he is right. If it works in IE, then because  the `img src` part gets ignored. The raw image will be output to the browser and `base64_encode` does never take place

Comment: Why downvote? Id certaily DOES what I said - please read my edited comment.

Comment: Please explain with `ob_start()`.  How do you use it?

Comment: I am happy that you are happy then ;]

Answer (score 11):

Because [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) outputs bool or image stream directly to output.
So, in order to get image data you should use output buffers like this:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$image = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because the `data:` URI scheme is extremely limited and good to use unless there is absolutely no way around it.

In Internet Explorer, for example, this doesn't work at all until IE 8; and in there, there is a [global 32 kilobyte limitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for data: URIs.

Comment: So your saying do it another way?

Comment: @Mark what do you need data: URIs for in the first place?

Comment: Captcha experiment. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692969/captcha-encryption

Comment: I need to display it to the user without saving it

Comment: @Mark  Why? To emphasize, what you are planning to do will not work at all in Internet Explorer 7. Can you really live with that?

Comment: Im the author of the other question :P.  But how can I do it so that the user can type what they see?

Comment: Is there simply a better way?  What would that be

Comment: @Mark I'm still not entirely sure what the core issue is, but many Captcha solutions use the user's session to store data the user is not supposed to see.

Comment: Would this be what I'm looking for http://www.articlesnatch.com/Article/How-To-Create-Captcha-With-Php/765335

Comment: @Mark maybe (I don't know the article), or something like it. Most CAPTCHA solutions use sessions to transfer their data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your image as a PNG first, and then read from it to get its contents as a value.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

imagepng() does not return the PNG file.  It outputs it directly to the browser and then returns a boolean meaning success or failure.

(from php.net:)
PHP internally works with a temporary file when sending the image to the browser, so you'll gain nothing by calling imagepng() twice.

Comment: You can enclose imagepng() between ob_start() and ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); to get the image, but it uses a temporary file anyway.