# php : display image resource

Tags: php, html, image

I feel quite stupid but I can't understand how to display the output of the imagepng() function.

What I currently do is (and it works fine) :

`<img src=<?php echo getImage($element); ?> />`

```
function getImage($element){
    return $bdd[$element]; // the result is a string with the path to the image
}
```

But I would love to draw some circles on the image, so here is what I would like to do (and it does not work) :

`<img src=<?php echo getImage($element); ?> />`

```
function getImage($element){
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($bdd[$element]);
    $ellipseColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
    imagefilledellipse($image, 100, 100, 10, 10, $ellipseColor);
    imagepng($image);

    return $image // why does that image resource not display ?
}
```

But it does not display anything else than symbols.. I assume it returns a full image and not a path to the image.. so How should I display my image with the circle on it ?

ps : I also tried to create a page getImage.php that would be called by `<img src=<?php echo 'getImage.php?element=' . $element; ?> />` but with no success

Comment: _what is the result here_: Just read the Manual page, http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php, this function returns bool, true/false.

Comment: yes but what is`$image` ?

Comment: Have you read manual yet?

Comment: @Arcyno: `$image` is `resource`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Comment: Actually I read that. Let's rephrase my question :  how can I display this resource on my website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do something like this

```
<img src="image.php">
```

And in the image.php you use your code

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($bdd[$element]);
$ellipseColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
imagefilledellipse($image, 100, 100, 10, 10, $ellipseColor);
imagepng($image);
```

Comment: I didn't know a PHP file could be used as "src=" (+1), first time I see this. For those who can't make "image.php" to work, I made it work by adding `ob_start();` at the beginning and `ob_end_flush();` and `ob_end_clean();` at the end (just **before** `imagepng($image);`).

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez could please give reference not docs how did you guessed or found about these ob_XXX() calls, because it's been a whole day of grief, trying different thumbnail creator codes that did not want to display this image resource. thanks

Comment: @Meryem, try this answer ► https://stackoverflow.com/a/3695085/3298930

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my answer on how to display the image inside an HTML page :
I need to put the code in another file `displayImage.php` and make a call to this page from the `<img>`tag :

**Main file with html tag:**

```
<img src="displayImage.php?element='<?php echo $element; ?> />
```

**displayImage.php :**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/png');
$image = imagecreatefrompng($bdd[$element]);
$ellipseColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);
imagefilledellipse($image, 100, 100, 10, 10, $ellipseColor);
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy( $image );

?>
```